# Detect when bind occurs in mvvmcross

Tags: mvvmcross

Hi i need to intercept when bind occur in mvvmcross project.

I have my MvxCollectionViewCell that i bind:

```
public ProjectsCollectionCell (IntPtr handle) 
    : base (string.Empty, handle)
{
    this.DelayBind(() => {

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ProjectsCollectionCell, ViewItem>();
        set.Bind (lblTitle).To (prj => prj.MnemonicId);
        set.Bind (lblDescription).To (prj => prj.Description);
        set.Bind(imgPhoto).For (s => s.Image).WithConversion("ImageArray").To(prj => prj.Image);
        set.Apply();

        if (imgPhoto.Image != null) {
            this.imgPhoto.Layer.RasterizationScale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;
            this.imgPhoto.Layer.ShouldRasterize = true;
            this.imgPhoto.Layer.BorderWidth = 10;
            this.imgPhoto.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
            this.imgPhoto.Layer.CornerRadius = 8f;
            this.imgPhoto.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            this.imgPhoto.Layer.Position = new PointF(imgPhoto.Frame.Left - 80, imgPhoto.Frame.Bottom);
            this.imgPhoto.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(-0.05f);
        };
    });
}
```

i want to intercept when the content of the 'imgPhoto' change.

Is there an event to subscribe?

Could you suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to detect when the `Image` on your cell's `DataContext` changes, then one way to do this is to add the property to your cell and to bind that property to your `DataContext` - e.g.

```
  private byte[] _bytes;
  public byte[] Bytes
  {
      get { return _bytes; }
      set
      {
          _bytes = value;
          // your code here...
      }
  }

  public ProjectsCollectionCell (IntPtr handle) 
       : base (string.Empty, handle)
  {

       this.DelayBind(() => {

             var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ProjectsCollectionCell, ViewItem>();
             set.Bind(_hook).For(h => h.CurrentSource);
             set.Bind (lblTitle).To (prj => prj.MnemonicId);
             set.Bind (lblDescription).To (prj => prj.Description);
             set.Bind(this).For(s => s.Bytes).WithConversion("ImageArray").To(prj => prj.Image);
             set.Apply();

             // etc
         });
  }
```

---

As an alternative, you might also want to consider subclassing whatever type `imgPhoto` is and providing a new property on that object. For an example of this approach, see the `AnimatingText` properties in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/n33-animating-data-bound-text-changes.html